# Cognito authorizer ignored on API Gateway method test invoke

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

For some reason, Cognito authorizer gets ignored when I test invoke the method (It works with Postman and any client requests though). I pass the idToken on the Header Authorization so I can use `$context.authorizer.claims.sub` as my uuid on request transformation, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the test invoke ignores any pre-integration steps, including authorization and throttle/quota check by API Key. We'd like to support a full end-to-end test invoke in the future, but for now you'll have to rely on end-to-end testing via the deployed API.

Answer (score 1):

When you test Cognito Authorizer itself, then you have to use ID token, not the Access token . When you call API Gateway from Postman(or any client tool), then you need to use `access token`

This video could be helpful as it shows step by step "Secure API Gateway using Cognito" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9crTLAT_4uY